# Sort a list alphabetically first and then numerically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, sorting

How can I sort a list of strings alphabetically first and then numerically in Python?

Eg:

```
Given list: li = ['4', '1', '3', '9', 'Z', 'P', 'V', 'A']
```

I want the following output after sorting:

```
sorted_list = ['A', 'P', 'V', 'Z', '1', '3', '4', '9']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sorted(sorted_list, key=lambda x: (x.isnumeric(),int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x))
```

this sorts also by value of the integer

Comment: `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (1, int(x)) if x.isnumeric() else (0, x))`.

Comment: Wow, quite bizarre how python compares integers with strings. Basically any string will always be greater than any int.

Comment: @matvs No, the 1st element of the tuples is guaranteed to be different, so the 2nd element is always compared like with like.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. The desired output can achieved by using [**`str.isdigit`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

```
sorted(l,key=lambda x:(x.isdigit(),x))
# ['A', 'P', 'V', 'Z', '1', '3', '4', '9']
```

**NOTE :** This solution doesn't handle digits more than one. Please take a look at [@Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855506/12416453) answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['4', '1', '3', '9', 'Z', 'P', 'V', 'A']
number = []
alphabet = []
for l in list1:
    if l.isnumeric():
        number.append(l)
    else:
        alphabet.append(l)

number = sorted(number)
alphabet = sorted(alphabet)
list1 = alphabet + number
print(list1)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name. Also, this fails to sort in numeric order when the numbers have more than one digit.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want it to take in consideration negative numbers, decimals and lower-case letters:

```py
li = ['A', 'b', '-400', '1.3', '10', '42', 'V', 'z']

threshold = abs(min(float(x) for x in li if not x.isalpha())) +  ord('z') + 1
sorted_list = sorted(li,
                     key=lambda x: ord(x) if x.isalpha() else threshold + float(x))
```

`sorted_list`:

```
['A', 'V', 'b', 'z', '-400', '1.3', '10', '42']
```